# Subclass Inheritance

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I subclassed `UIScrollView` and added some methods and properties that I'd like to use on a `UITableView`. Is it possible to make a table view inherit from my custom scrollView instead of UIScrollView?

Comment: The problem is that Apple control the `UITableView` source code, not you.

Comment: Yea I know, I just wanted to know if there was a way to circumvent this with a hack or something

Comment: I am not sure (and cant check now, as no mac with me), what I did here, I wrote something here and got 5 downvotes in 1 minutes. Please have a look : http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5984111/tablemultiplescrolls-zip-95k?da=y

Comment: yes I think it's possible but can you used UIScrollView then again add UIview instead of UITableView.don't set property just add in your view controller.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: I think you are right, but your answer applies only to OS X. - On iOS, UITableView is a direct *subclass* of UIScrollView. Therefore making UITableView inherit from a custom subclass of UIScrollView is not possible or at least very tricky. - On OS X, NSTableView is *embedded* in a NSScrollView, but not a *subclass*. Therefore, you can subclass NSScrollView and embed a standard NSTableView.

Comment: @MartinR: Here you go, That is a lesson for me, **Now I am learning iOS slooowly slooowly :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the strong features of Objective-C is categories.

Excerpt From [Objective-C: Categories](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html):

> As an alternative to subclassing, Objective-C categories provide a
>   means to add methods to a class. What’s intriguing, is that any
>   methods that you add through a category become part of the class
>   definition, so to speak. In other words, if you add a method to the
>   NSString class, any instance, or subclass, of NSString will have
>   access to that method.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extend `UIScrollView`. Within the scope of the extension (or category respectively) the extension should apply to all subclasses too. However, I never tried that myself.

You cannot subclass `UIScrollView` (let's say named `MyScrollView`) and then make an existing `UITableView` subclass of your subclass MyScrollView instead of `UIScrollView`. But extending `UIScrollView` should work.

However, if you provide a method abc in your extension `MySuperView` while `UITableView` also implements abc then the abc of UITableView will be invoked. 
Therefore I do not really see the advantage of this construction vs. extending or subclassing UITableView directly.

Comment: Would I be able to make my UIScrollView category conform to UIScrollViewDelegate?

Comment: Again, I never did THAT myself, but yes, why not? So you are going to build a view object that serves as its own delegate?